# Unexpected white space using function in template literal

Tags: javascript, html, whitespace, template-literals

I'm making an app using API from one website that stream music and I run into a problem.

When I click on play button I'm getting an error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input* and when I click on it it shows only this: *document.getElementById(*

Here is my code:

```
fetch(`https://api.deezer.com/playlist/3155776842`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then((data) =>{
let output = ''

data.tracks.data.forEach(track => {
    output += `<div class="artist">
    <a href="${track.artist.link}"><img src="${track.album.cover_medium}"></img></a>
    <div class="info">
    <p class="title">${track.artist.name}</p>
    <div>
    <audio id="${track.id}" src=${track.preview}></audio>
        <a onclick="document.getElementById("${track.id}").play()"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>
        <a onclick="document.getElementById("${track.id}").pause()"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>`

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output
});
})
```

The problem is in *track.id*

In audio tag im getting expected line:

```
<audio id="123456"> src="www.something.com/img"
```

but on *a* tag, I get space on left and I think that's the problem:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById(" 123456").play()"><i class="fas 
fa-play"></i></a>
```

I tried using common-tags but it doesn't work. Also tried *trim()* but then I got an error: *trim is not a function*

Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting of your `<a>` tag. By using double-quotes within double-quotes, you're creating an element with `onclick="document.getElementById("`, followed by a bunch of garbage. Change it to `...getElementById('${track.id}')` (single quotes) instead.

Comment: @TylerRoper that's it. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('123456').play()"><i class="fas 
fa-play"></i></a>
```

You have to use single quotes. Double quotes cancel each other out